# If $G$ is a topological group and $H$ a normal subgroup, then if $H$ and $G/H$ are both totally disconnected then so is $G$.

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

I encountered a statement in a proof that said if $G$ is a topological group and $H$ a normal subgroup, then if $H$ and $G/H$ are both totally disconnected then so is $G$. I have no idea how it is obvious or why it is left without any proof or hints but to me it seems really tough to see a proof. Has someone here encountered such theorem or can help with its proof?

Comment: You wrote a complete nonsense (namely, a complete triviality) of the kind: "If A and B are red, then A is red". Please check this carefully and this is why David commented what he did. Now make sure what you **really** meant to write/ask. Perhaps the last $G$ is supposed to be $H$? Perhaps the second $G$ should be $H$?

Comment: The first $G$ should probably be an $H$.

Comment: I have fixed the typing error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assume that $C\subseteq G$ is a connected subset. We will show that $C$ is a point which proves that $G$ is totally disconnected.

Consider the projection $\pi:G\to G/H$. It follows that $\pi(C)$ is connected and since $G/H$ is totally disconnected then $\pi(C)$ is a point. Therefore $C\subseteq gH$ for some $g\in G$. And since $H$ is totally disconnected then so is $gH$ and therefore $C$ has to be a point, which completes the proof. $\Box$

Note that "being a group" is not really important here. This can be generalized as follows:

> Assume that $X$ is a topological space and $\sim$ an equivalence relation such that $X/\sim$ is totally disconnected and all equivalence classes $[x]_\sim$ are totally disconnected. Then $X$ is totally disconnected as well.

The only property of topological groups that we used is that $x\mapsto gx$ is a homeomorphism and so all cosets are totally disconnected. In particular $H$ doesn't have to be normal.

Comment: Why is $C \subset gH$

Comment: @blabla Because $C\subseteq \pi^{-1}(\pi(C))$ and the preimage of a point via $\pi$ is a coset.